# Migration .Net core App from VS2015 to VS2019 in C#

Tags: c#

How to Migrate .Net core App project from VS2015 to VS2019?

In VS2015 used netcoreapp2.1

Comment: Don't really get the question. Why are you mentioning Visual Studio? If you really mean, what you are saying and you want to migrate the csproj / sln formats to a possible format of the new visual studio, just open it with Visual Studio 2019 and if a migration needs to take place Visual Studio will inform you and do it.

Comment: App and visual studio both are non related. Have you tried opening your project in VS 2019?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects?view=vs-2019&preserve-view=true

Comment: I need to migrate .sln file.

I opened that solution in VS2019. It didnt report any error.

I need clarification about Is we need to update any core app version in .csproj file?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply install the VS2019 and open the projet with this one.
Don't forget to restore nuget packages before regenerate the solution.